# Samsung k zoom 5.8ghz

Tags: samsung

I was wondering whether it was possible to allow a rooted Samsung K Zoom to use the 5.8GHz channel? I was reading that I might have to edit the wpa_supplicant.conf to allow for 5.8GHz. In addition, I was wondering if the wifi card of the k zoom can even handle 5.8GHz?

**Edit**

To clarify I know the phone has 5GHZ band access. However I am looking for it to access the 5.8Ghz( or 5.7GHz is fine) CHANNEL. Around channel 149. Other samsung phones in the same family can, but not the k zoom. I was wondering if it is possible to enable it access to the higher 5GHZ channels; whether this is a software block or whether the hardware can actually not handle it. I have tried changing the p2p settings in wpa configuration file with no luck. Which was suggested from research I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try third party kernels/ROMs which may enable that spectrum but the legality may be an issue depending on your location. It's possible it's still a hardware limitation but more likely is that it's a software limitation.

You may have some luck fiddling with wpa_supplicant.conf per [this post](http://androidforums.com/threads/need-help-to-unlock-wifi-5-8-ghz.913684/#post-6943612).

> As a hint, you need to look into wpa_supplicant.conf to use all the
>   5.8Ghz frequencies with the parameters:
>
> p2p_oper_reg_class=
>
> p2p_oper_channel=
>
> For me Korea is 124 and 149
>
> But yes, you need to be rooted

Comment: The editing the p2p part I mean

Comment: You try rebooting after? Could also try wiping dalvik cache. Maybe fiddle with `p2p_disabled=1` > `0`.

Comment: I did reboot. Didn't try the second thing though.

Comment: what I found was when I changed `p2p_disabled`, and rebooted. The value changed back to what it was originally.